# How to access the variable of a class instantiated in another class?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, integer

I have two classes: `DashboardViewController` (having an integer variable 'userid') and `LoginViewController`. I instantiate a `DashboardViewController` and set the value of `userid` from `LoginViewController`, but when I print the value of `userid` in `DashboardViewController`, it prints `0`. Could someone please help me with this?

This is how I instantiate `DashboardViewController` from `LoginViewController` ('serverOutput' is a string containing a single integer value:

```
DashboardViewController *newView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
newView.userid = [serverOutput intValue];
```

I then go to `DashboardViewController` and put:

```
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",userid]);
```

and this prints 0 instead of the integer value it should. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `[serverOutput intValue]` is returning a non-0 value? Log `[serverOutput intValue]`. Keep an eye out for unexpected whitespace in the string.

Comment: Notes: You should set `newView.userId` before you call `presentViewController`. Also, your `NSLog` should be: `NSLog(@"%d", userid);`. `NSLog` already handles string formats.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thanks, I am new to XCode and your suggestions helped a lot! And yes [serverOutput intValue] returns a non-0 value, I don't know if its because it is only a single digit. Do you know a better way of converting the string 'serverOutput' into an integer?

Comment: You now know that your call to `newView.userId` is being set to a non-zero value. Now you need to determine why it is logging as zero. Where in `DashboardViewController` is your log of `userId`? Make sure it is being called after you set it in your `LoginViewController`. Also, change the log to print out `self.userId` instead of just `userId`. See if that helps.

Comment: @rmaddy- yeah I get the expected output now. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5488135/objective-c-how-to-access-an-instance-variable-from-another-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your code :

```
DashboardViewController *newView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
newView.userid = [serverOutput intValue];
```

By this code :

```
DashboardViewController *newView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
newView.userid = [serverOutput intValue];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And if you still not get your answer,Then there is an alternate method too...

There is an easy approach to solve your problem. Just make a global variable in `Appdelegate` class. I mean ,make a `NSString` property in `AppDelegate.h` and synthesize it.

In `AppDelegate.h:`

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *GlobalStr;
```

And synthesize it in `AppDelegate.m`.

Now make Object of `AppDelegate` in `LoginViewController` :

```
AppDelegate *obj = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
DashboardViewController *newView = [[DashboardViewController alloc] init];
obj.GlobalStr = [serverOutput intValue];
[self presentViewController:newView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then go to `DashboardViewController` and put:

```
AppDelegate *obj = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
userid = [obj.GlobalStr intValue];
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",userid]);
```